# upload photo to server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using this code for upload photo:

```
    MemoryStream photoStream = new MemoryStream();
    e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(photoStream);
    photoStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] buf = photoStream.ToArray();

    string str = Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
    string fileBase64 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str);

    // Send fileBase64 to server
```

The server then decode the base64 string and name it "test.jpt".

the problem is that paint doesn't open the image uploaded on my server.

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your base64 string is incorrect. I have written this code, here it is, it works:

```
BitmapImage a = new BitmapImage();
a.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(a);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
wb.SaveJpeg(ms, a.PixelWidth, a.PixelHeight, 0, 50); //50 is a quality of a photo
imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```